# Total Run Time for All Users for My Application

Tags: android

I am new at Android. I have an idea and i want to know which user, how long time run my application since he/she install to his/her device. (in day/hour/min format)

These datas will hold in SQL table(s).

- What type of techs and logic should i use?
- When traffic size is very huge for a normal host?
- Is Android allow to access this type of information?

Comment: You would need to inform your users about the collection of their data. In general, I don't see how this could be useful at all.

Comment: so i dont want to collect their private data such as location, tel number etc. This information only necessary for me and if my app be successful i will share it with my users.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

Comment: Yes, there are lots of statistics that you will be able to glean from Google Analytics.